# hear a 3D drum as a solid shape or as a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, spectral-theory

Weyl's 'Can one hear the shape of a drum' is well explained in wiki. I have programmed the Laplacian for a given shape (2D), the "sound" is function of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.

However, I cannot find any documents explaining the sound of a 3D shape: either as a solid shape or as a surface (void inside). Do researches on acoustics cover this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same idea, just solve the wave equation, but now in 3D:

$$
\nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}
$$

And this is a very active field. Here are some examples

1. [Helioseismology:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helioseismology) Propagation of acoustic waves in stars, allows you to figure out their internal structure
2. [Medical imaging](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23643056) Use of acoustic waves to produce images of biological tissues
3. [Reflection seismology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_seismology) Oil/water exploration by using the acoustic wave equation

The list is pretty large actually!

Comment: 1 and 3 sounds very cool! I never think about such applications.